# open text file with argument argv[1] command line

Tags: c++

How can I replace `ifstream infile("jobs.txt");` with `argv[1]` command line?

This is my main function :

```
int main()
{   
    int arrSize=0;
    vector<Process> procs;
    vector<Process> proc;
int element1, element2, element3;
char comma;
ifstream infile("jobs.txt");
      
if (!infile.is_open()) {
    cerr << "Can't open file" << endl;
}
else {
    while (infile >> element1 >> comma >> element2 >> comma >> element3)
    {
Process proc{element1, element2, element3};
procs.push_back(proc);
    }
}
arrSize=procs.size();
cout << procs.size() << endl;

int n = sizeof(proc) / sizeof(proc[0]);
  
findavgTime(procs.data(), static_cast<int>(procs.size()));
}
```

Comment: Is the confusion that you need to change the signature of `main` in order to add `argc` and `argv`?

Comment: There are millions of examples out there, including in pretty much any textbook on C or C++.  Your function signature should be `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and you should ensure that `argc` is at _least_ 2.

Comment: I guess, I've never done before and still trying to figure out, saw some examples the way how you said but not sure how exactly will work int.argc with my string file

Comment: What do you mean?  Just try it.  Write a program that simply displays all the arguments and exits.  Are you confused about what `argc` actually represents?  This is the subject of introductory C++ book material.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a skeleton you can use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: foo <input filename>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream in(argv[1]);
    if (!in)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open file: '" << argv[1] << "'\n";
        return 1;
    }

    //Do important stuff here.
}
```

Worth noting that

```
int n = sizeof(proc) / sizeof(proc[0]);
```

does not give you the size of a `std::vector`. Use the `proc.size()` as you have with `procs`.

Comment: Returning zero when a program obviously did not succeed isn't good practice.

Comment: Fix your own answer before criticising this one ;)

Comment: @paddy Okay. :)

Comment: @Casey I assume anyone that is interested in checking that return value outside the program is capable of changing it to something that suits them.

Comment: @RetiredNinja That's...not how that works. The return value is specifically designed to notify the OS (and by extension, automation systems like batch files) that zero means "The operation completed successfully" and anything else means it didn't.

Comment: @Casey I am aware of how it works. If a tree falls in the forest and nobody is listening did it make a sound?

Comment: Meh... It's not an error per-se, it can be the correct behavior when no argument is provided. There certainly isn't any convention that says a lack of arguments is an error verses a simple exit when you can proceed no further. (that said, I usually provide usage on `std::cerr` and `return 1;`), but there is nothing wrong with providing usage on `std::cout` and `return 0;`...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm pretty sure not being able to open a file you need to open in order to continue is a problem, hence, the operation did not complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it? You need to actually add the command line arguments to `main`'s signature though.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
//...
    if(argc <= 1) { //Prevents out-of-bounds access to argv array.
        return 1;
    }
    ifstream infile(argv[1]);
//...
}
```

Comment: I used the code that you suggested and seems that compile is ok with it but for some reason nothing is opening, also there is no error. Text File is in the same folder as my .cpp file

Comment: @DenisGojinetchi You need to provide the filepath as an argument to your program when running it. `myprogram.exe jobs.txt` if the file is in the working path of your executable. (I don't know the OS you are using nor if you are using an IDE so I cannot give specifics of providing the command line arguments through them)

Comment: I use Windows OS and code on Visual Studio. Where do I provide the filepath as argument?

Comment: For debugging purposes inside the IDE: `Debug > [Project Name] Debug Properties > Configuration Properties > Debugging > Command Arguments`. Type in `jobs.txt`. This assumes you have the default working directory `$(ProjectDir)` and the file exists in that directory (which is usually right next to your source code). Providing the filepath outside of the IDE is equal to above.